# Script.aculo.us Drag 'n' Drop - Revert onEnd condition

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I'm trying to **revert** a draggable if a condition returns false. So for instance, I'd like to do the following:

```
new Draggable('myelement', {
    onStart: function() {
      // do something
    },
    onEnd: function() {
      var condition = getConditionVal();
      if (!condition) revert to original position
      else {
         // do something else
      }
    }
});
```

Would this be possible? Not sure if "droppables" would work in this case since the droppable area changes dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Scriptaculous drag/drop is designed to have all kinds of fancy stuff easily added.
Of course you can edit the revert option any time.

To change the value of the revert-option of an draggable, just reset the revert-option:

```
var myDraggable = new Draggable('myelement', {
    onStart: function() {
      // do something
    },
    onEnd: function() {
      var condition = getConditionVal();
      if (!condition){
          myDraggable.options.revert = true;
      }
      else {
          myDraggable.options.revert = false;
          // do something else
      }
    };
});
```

Scriptaculous [does the revert right after the onEnd event call](https://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/blob/master/src/dragdrop.js#L418),
which gives us the possibility of changing it before it will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Scriptaculous's drag/drop code wasn't designed to have conditional revert. You can have revert or no revert. That's all, sadly.

This feature has been requested many times but scripty/prototype has waned in popularity over the years, so it's doubtful this feature will ever be added.